# Containers running on ARM

Tags: linux, arm, lxc, openvz, container

I've been doing some research and decided to implement OpenVZ since it allows each container to be isolated from other containers, unlike LXC.

However, OpenVZ is still not supported for ARM processors. Any way to work around the container isolation issue in LXC?

Answer (score 0):

OpenVZ is dead (RIP) so it's lxc or micro containers (Docker has been ported to arm - although I haven't tested it).

The isoloation issues still exist, although lots of workloads don't need to be privileged. In those cases isolation is a non issue.

If you want isolation, you'll need to use something else, like qemu. It should run ok on arm, although without kvm you'll take a performance hit (software virtualization on a low speed machine...). Apparently rpi 2 onwards supports kvm in theory, but I think it involves some hackery.